# Trouble with downloading with youtube-dl

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube-dl

I tried a lot of things in cmd and in Python but it always downloads in WEBM Video File (.webm) or mp4.
I don't understand why does it do it because in code I added preferences and in them put only audio and said that format is mp3.

```
ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'extractaudio': True,
            'audioformat' : "mp3"
           }

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['link'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem adding `'postprocessors'` in `ydl_opts`:

```
ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                'extractaudio': True,
                'postprocessors': [{
                  'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                  'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                  'preferredquality': '192',
            }]
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['link'])
```

this should download a second file in mp3 format, and then delete the first file.